# LINQ returning EnumerableRowCollection

Tags: vb.net, linq

I need to get the name of fee according to a specific id, I am trying to get the column directly instead of the whole row.

I have the following code

```
Dim fee As EnumerableRowCollection(Of String) = (From row In dtFee.AsEnumerable _
                                    Where row.Field(Of SqlInt32)("idFee").Value = idFee _
                                    Select row.Field(Of SqlString)("name").Value)
```

but when i access it through :

```
lblIdFee.Text = fee.FirstOrDefault
```

i get an exception of invalid convertion but if a declare the results as

```
  Dim fee = ...
```

And if I get the result from fee through the toString() method because i do not have available FirstOrDefault i get:

```
System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection`1[System.String]
```

I don't know if a missing some reference library.

Comment: you should look into using strongly type datatables. It will make your LINQ statements much cleaner and you won't have to manually type the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your variable type to

```
Dim fee As IEnumerable(Of String) ...
```

You are projecting to a collection of string values, not a collection of `DataRow`s

Comment: I still get the exception of _the specified convertion is invalid_

Comment: Try using `Integer` and `String` instead of `SqlInt32` and `SqlString` in your query.  Is either field nullable?

Comment: Correct, that was the problem (using sql's version).